C++ - Can I make the use of std::map thread-safe by storing value with its pointer?
There exists a piece of code in the project(C++98) I am maintaining that does some poll/start/stop stuff to processes. These processes' metadata are stored in a std::map in a form <process id, pointer to process instance>. And there are two threads accessing the map after initialization. One keeps polling process status from the map and sending it to the client side, which is read only. And another thread handles start/stop request from the client side and then start/stop the given process.
Now here comes the problem. Read and write operations of both threads are not protected by locks, so the project has some wired behaviours. I want to add locks to make it thread-safe.
My plan is to first use a rw-lock for the whole map, and then one rw-lock for each process. The lock order will be like this:
1. Poll process status:
acquire readlock of the whole map -> acquire readlock of the target process -> some read operation to the process -> release readlock of the target process -> release readlock of the whole map

2. Start/stop process:
acquire readlock of the whole map -> acquire writelock of the target process -> some write operation to the process -> release writelock of the target process -> release readlock of the whole map

3. Write to the map:
acquire writelock of the whole map -> some write operation to the map -> release writelock of the whole map

In my view:

Writing to the process only acquires readlock of the map, which has a better lock granularity than locking the whole map with a writelock.

I access the process through its pointer, which is not modified when I polling/starting/stopping the process.


My question is if this design feasible? Is there any thread-unsafe operation in my design?

Do you actually need RW locks here? Assuming that you don't have that high of a contention for your data structure, and individual accesses are typically short, simple explicit locks (i.e. normal mutexes) would probably be enough? And if you do have high contention, maybe you should redesign your entire data structure? (9 times out of 10, RW locks are more trouble than they are worth it IMHO.) Other than that, I don't see an immediate error in your locking logic, but without actual code it's hard to tell if it's correct or not.

@chris_se Thanks for the detailed advice! I check the code and find the polling thread(read) traverses all processes every second and each individual access is short, while the starting/stopping thread(write) rarely access the map(less than 50 times a day) and individual access is long. The response to the client side write operation should be as quick as possible, so writer starvation of rwlock is not acceptable. So it could be better to use mutex than RW lock for map and processes?

From what you describe a read-write lock doesn't make sense at all, because if you have only one thread that does the read operations, then it can't ever share the read lock with any other thread. So use a mutex in that case. Note that if the long operation from the writer is active, the read thread will need to wait on that for some time. (But that also occurs with a RW lock.) But I do believe that you might want to think how to avoid the long lock duration at all by changes to your data structures. I don't understand your underlying problem enough to give better guidance though.

@chris_se Your explanation helps me a lot. My problem is to make the multi-threading code thread-safe and make the granularity of locks reasonable. According to your advice, I will use mutex for both map scoop and processes scope. And I believe redesigning the data structure is needed as well to avoid long wait duration. I will try these on the project. Thanks.
